# FFMPEG не определяет координаты на version 4.2.4

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

ffmpeg version 4.2.4 Copyright

```
crop=$(ffmpeg -i '/var/****/1.mp4' -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print $NF }' | tail -1)
echo crop
```

Раньше стояла v 2***, в результате выполнения данной команды получал в переменную координаты по которым в дальнейшем и обрезал видио. Обновил до v4, ответ пустой.

Затем установил mplayer

mplayer /var/****/1.mp4 -vop cropdetect -ao null 2>/dev/null

Ответ точно тот же, не знаю с чем это связано. С версией либо, в чем еще может быть дело?

Comment: Ну а без awk и tail что пишет-то?

Comment: Пусто, точнее `(None,None)`